# Is it possible to include timezones in list of roles?

Tags: postgresql, psql

Can a list of postgresql roles be generated that includes the role's timezone?

I've learned, and tested, that a psql session will take on the timezone of the role used at login.  Of course we can alter a role to a particular time zone with:

```
# ALTER ROLE testUser SET timezone TO 'America/Chicago';
```

But exactly how can that information be accessed to produce a list so that all the roles can be checked?  I've tried \du+, but that returns very limited information.  Surprisingly (to me anyway) the information_schema doesn't seem to include the timezone values.  Internet searches have so far not helped in this quest.

Where else can I try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The settings of a role can be retrieved from `pg_db_role_setting`, it's an `text[]` array of `<setting name>=<setting value>`. So this needs an `unnest()` and a `split_part()` to get to the individual components. Furthermore, as a setting can be set for a specific database (see the `IN DATABASE` option for the `ALTER ROLE` command), we need to involve the databases from `pg_database`. We cross join them with all the roles from `pg_authid`. To also include settings that aren't bound to a database but are valid for all databases we `UNION ALL` an empty database with a zero OID to the list of databases. From that we can left join the role settings.

So the following will give you the value set for `timezone` for all databases (including the "all" or "none" database) and all roles or null if the `timezone` isn't set for a user in a database.

```
SELECT rol.rolname,
       dat.datname,
       split_part(kvp.kvp, '=', 2) timezone
       FROM pg_authid rol
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT dat.oid,
                               dat.datname
                               FROM pg_database dat
                         UNION ALL
                         SELECT 0::oid oid,
                                '' datname) dat
            LEFT JOIN pg_db_role_setting set
                      ON set.setdatabase = dat.oid
                         AND set.setrole = rol.oid
            LEFT JOIN LATERAL unnest(set.setconfig) kvp (kvp)
                              ON lower(split_part(kvp.kvp, '=', 1)) = 'timezone'
       ORDER BY 1,
                2;
```

Comment: Wow!  An answer almost immediately AND a few things to do more research on.  (It's interesting that a setting can be set for a specific db - this is maybe new to me.)  Thanks stick bit!